# Looping an oscillator in p5js

Tags: javascript, ajax, audio, processing, p5.js

I'm having trouble creating a sequence of sounds using an oscillator with a for loop in p5js.  I'm getting my parameters from an ajax request and I verify the data.  I can't find any examples of this online, so maybe there's a more library specific way of generating sequences of sounds.  My approach that doesn't work goes something like this:

getParams is called upon pushing a button.  Nothing goes wrong here...

```
function getParams(mode){
  console.log("trying to get tune...");
  var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
  var mode = mode;
  $.ajax({
    url: window.location.href,
    type: "POST",
    data : { mode : mode,
             csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrftoken,
   },
    success: function(json){
             genTune(json);
  },          
error : function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
              console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
    },
  })
}
```

genTune is fed data from getParams.

```
function genTune(json){
  playing = true;
  var level = json["level"] + 4;
  a = json["a"];
  b = json["b"];
  aFreq = json["a_freq"];
  bFreq = json["b_freq"];

  for (var i = 0; i < level; i++) {
    console.log("i = " + i);
    if (i===a){
      osc.freq(aFreq * 10);
      osc.amp(0.5, 0.05);
      osc.start();
      osc.stop(0.5);

    } else if (i===b){       
      osc.freq(bFreq * 10);
      osc.amp(0.5, 0.05);
      osc.start();
      osc.stop(0.5);

    } else {       
      osc.freq(NOTE_FREQS[random(NOTE_FREQS.length-1)]);
      osc.amp(0.5, 0.05);
      osc.start();
      osc.stop(0.5);
    }

  }

   }
```

EDIT: The loop works and the message is iterated now that I've fixed a stupid error, but sound is only played once.  Can anyone tell me how to make a sequence of sounds with a loop?  Thanks!

To clarify, there are no console errors in Firebug.

Comment: What is the value of `level`?

Comment: @Kevin Workman   Thanks for noticing that, it wasn't in the json so it was null.  Just added it and now the loop is working (console message iterates), but sound is only being played once.  Is this not the correct way to loop oscillators?

Comment: I don't really know, I've never worked with this. One thing that occurs to me is that this is all happening in a for loop, which executes in a fraction of a second. Maybe you want to space things out over more time?